# Force TeamCity to build on a specific agent

Tags: teamcity

Is it possible, without disabling all other connected agents, to force TeamCity to build on a specific agents machine?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Under `Build Configuration Settings` go to `Agent Requirements` and set an `Explicit Requirement` for the specific agent name:

**Parameter Name:** `system.agent.name`

**Condition:** `equals`

**Value:** `YOUR_SPECIFIC_AGENT_NAME`

Answer (score 22):

For one time run you can click on the 3 dots next to "Run" and define on what agent you want to run.
For a long term configuration you should use the Agent Requirements of the build.
You can add a system property to the agent by editing the file ...\buildAgent\conf\buildAgent.properties

```
system.special.property=true
```

Then you can define on the Agent Requirements to check the property `system.special.property` **exists**.

**EDIT**
With the new version of Teamcity (5.0.*) you can now edit the Agent and select the configuration you want to run there.
Agents, select an agent, Compatible Configurations, choose "Run selected configurations only".

Answer (score 1):

TeamCity > Administration > Agents > Select an Agent > "Compatible Configurations" tab:

Current run configuration policy: "Run assigned configurations only"

Click "+ Assign configurations"