# Run TeamCity Build Step on a specific Agent

Tags: macos, teamcity, build-agent

I've got TeamCity installed and working, and I need to have a build step run on a particular build agent (everything's running on Windows, but we have a Mac portion I need to build as well).

How do I tell the build step what agent I want it to run on? I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1600778/teamcity-force-teamcity-to-build-on-a-specific-agent), but that references an entire build; I just want a particular step to run on a given agent.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sharma is somewhat correct, and KIR has it completely correct.

I needed a build configuration for each server, Mac and Windows. Then I set a snapshot dependency from the Windows build on the Mac build (to make sure the Mac version builds completely first) and a artifact dependency from the same (to copy the resulting build output from the Mac to the Windows box). Then I modified the build process on the Windows box to include the artifacts, and voila, works like a charm.

Answer (score 3):

From what I am aware of, it is not possible. You may want a separate build configuration to build for mac.

Comment: Separate configuration + artifact/snapshot dependency between build configurations to pass artifacts from mac build to master build.